# Give each row in a list an ID

Tags: c#, list, winforms, gtfs

I'm trying to create a timetables.txt from other files, and I have this so far.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string Routes = @"C:\Users\peepee poopoo\gtfs\routes.txt";

        var column1 = new List<string>();
        var column2 = new List<string>();
        using (var rd = new StreamReader(Routes))
        {
            while (!rd.EndOfStream)
            {
                var splits = rd.ReadLine().Split(',');
                column1.Add(splits[0]);
                column2.Add(splits[1]);
            }
        }

        // print column1
        Console.WriteLine("Column 1:");
        foreach (var element in column1)
            Console.WriteLine(element);

        // print column2
        Console.WriteLine("Column 2:");
        foreach (var element in column2)
            Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
```

However, I need the first column of every row in the list to have a number that just counts up from 1. How can I do this?

Comment: Instead of creating a list of strings, why not create a class that contains an int and a string, and make a list of those.   Or you could use a `Dictionary<int,string>` instead of a `List`

Comment: @Neil I don't understand

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired output? It's not clear whether the *Columns* should be combined in a Row, plus the counter, or you actually need two separate collections as you have now.

Comment: The desired output would be similar to this: https://github.com/marintransit/marintransit-gtfs/blob/master/timetables.txt. I can grab all the info needed from other files but doing it programmatically is difficult.

Comment: No, it's not. Build a class model that contains all the parts you need, as public properties; get the parts from your input files and add these values to a new class object that describes a Row of your output. Then you can serialize your `List<class>` objects as you prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just see the code written below and add it.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionart<string, string>();
    using (var rd = new StreamReader(Routes))
    {
        while (!rd.EndOfStream)
        {
            var splits = rd.ReadLine().Split(',');
            dictionary.Add(splits[0], splits[1]);
        }
    }

    foreach(var item in dictionary)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "\t" + item.Value);
    }
```

Comment: Error at `dictionary.Add(splits[0], splits[1]);` : Cannot convert from string to int

Comment: Update: Have been trying and still can't fix this error.

Comment: First check at 0th index, It is integer value coming or not. It integer value is coming then do typecasting with code dictionary.Add(Convert.ToInt32(splits[0]), splits[1]);

Comment: That just gives `Cannot convert from string to System.IFormatProvider` for splits[1]

Comment: Otherwise you can just modify    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

Comment: Changing the dictionary to <string, string> worked, thanks!

Comment: Most welcome, please accept my answer also

Answer (score 0):

This was what worked:

```
string Routes = @"C:\Users\peepee poopoo\gtfs\routes.txt";

        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        using (var rd = new StreamReader(Routes))
        {
            while (!rd.EndOfStream)
            {
                var splits = rd.ReadLine().Split(',');
                dictionary.Add(splits[0], splits[1]);
                //dictionary.Add(splits[0], splits[1]);
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in dictionary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "\t" + item.Value);
        }
```

The output then becomes
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bkQ3.png)